# Upvote requirements using Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, voting, privileges, feedback

How does one simply (and quickly) provide feedback that an answer was helpful or vote UP on Stack Overflow without first establishing a reputation? I don't care about point games, but would still like to thank someone for their excellent answer, and subsequently saving me a bunch of time.

I'm fairly certain I'm asking this Stack Overflow-related question in the wrong place. I tried the tags meta.stackoverflow.com, getting started, and reputation, but they don't exist and can't be established without points.

Do I have to ask questions before I have the authorization to give any feedback?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges